# Landscape only UIViewController in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, landscape

I have `UITableViewController` in which on one tab is `UINavigationViewController`. `UINavigationController` root view controller is UITableViewController, and when clicked on cell, `UIViewController` appears which has to be locked in `Landscape`.

I want every Controller to be locked in `Portrait`, except the mentioned `UIViewController` that must be locked in `Portrait`.

**I have tried the following:**

**CustomTabBarController.m:**

```
#import "CustomTabBarController.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.h:**

```
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationController

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**And in UIViewController that must be locked in to Landscape, I have put:**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

But it doesn't work, I can rotate it to Landscape and it will stay locked in Landscape, but I want it to appear automatically in Landscape.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a big problem in the past with `UITabBarController` not respecting my supported interface orientations of displayed view controllers.

I solved the problem by sub-classing `UITabBarController` and capturing whenever an item was selected. I'd then call down to the view controller myself, ask it what the supported orientations are and force a rotation myself if needed. I would also call down to the selected view controller on rotations to set/change my supported orientations.

I implemented the `UITabBarDelegate` and used `didSelectItem` to capture tab switches. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override method

`- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the method  to block some orientations for a particular window:

```
– application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
```